# How can I save url into an array in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a watch-later extension for Google Chrome. This means, if I press a button that is in the extension, it saves the URL and the title of the web and shows it down of the button. If I press it, it redirects me to that URL.

The extension is working perfect if I save only a URL. But I want to save more than one. I think I should use an array, but I don't know how to implement it in this case.

What's wrong on this code? Thanks for your attention!

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(["activeTab", "nameOfTheTab"], function(items){
  var item = items.activeTab;
  document.getElementById('urlDude').href = item;
  document.getElementById('urlDude').innerHTML = items.nameOfTheTab;
  
});

saveItem.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

    var activeTab = tabs[0].url;
    var totalTabs = [];
    totalTabs.push(activeTab);
    var tabName = tabs[0].title;

    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "activeTab": totalTabs }, function(){  });
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "nameOfTheTab": tabName }, function(){  });
    document.getElementById('urlDude').href = tabs[0].url;
    document.getElementById('urlDude').innerHTML = tabName;

 });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./popus.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="saveItem">save</button>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a id="urlDude" target="_blank"><p>Hola</p></a>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Create an array and pass the array into set(), if you don't know how arrays work at all. Read a few tutorials to help you get started.

Comment: Hey, I've been searching a bit about set() but I think this wouldn't solve the issue. Why do you recommend using a Set()? Thanks!